# office 365 download on ubuntu

Tags: 15.04, microsoft-office

My school needs me to use office 365 but the online version is broken. Is it possible that I can get office 365 on ubuntu?

Leave a answer below.

Comment: It's not possible to use the Office 365 desktop applications on Ubuntu. They are Windows and Mac OS X only.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Office 365 can not be installed in Ubuntu (or in any Linux distributions). It is not supported by Wine also.

So the best option is to install VirtualBox or VMware in Ubuntu and install Windows 7 inside it. Then install Office 365 in Windows 7 inside the VM.

Comment: I can't because it takes too much room up.

Comment: You've no other options